# button onclick not responding with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "API's/Menus/RestaurantID.json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            var str = new String();
            var m=0;
            str+='<div id="displayMenu">';
            $.each(data, function(index, data) 
            {
                if(index==num)
                {

                    m=data.menu.MenuID;
                    //str+=data.menu.OmfID+'<br>';
                    //str+=data.menu.menu_name+'<br>';
                    if(data.menu.menu_description!=null)
                        str+=data.menu.menu_description+'<br>';
                    if(data.menu.menu_note!=null)
                        str+=data.menu.menu_note+'<br>';                    
                    str+=data.menu.currency_symbol+'<br>';
                    str+=data.menu.language+'<br>';
                    //if(data.menu.disabled!=null)
                        //str+=data.menu.disabled+'<br>';

                    str+=data.menu.menu_uid+'<br>';
                    str+=data.menu.menu_duration_name+'<br>';
                    str+=data.menu.menu_duration_time_start+'<br>';
                    str+=data.menu.menu_duration_time_end+'<br>';
                    //str+=data.menu.fDateAdded+'';
                }
            });

            str+='<div id="checkoutMenu">check out the menu?<br>';
            alert(m);

            str+="<button type='button' onclick='menu(m);'>Click Me!</button></div>";
</div>';
            str+= '</div>';
            document.getElementById("menusInfo").innerHTML=str;
        }
```

This is my JavaScript and the one thing that isnt working right now that i can't explain is that the onclick button doesn't want to run the function it is calling with variable m in the function call. My question is

1. How do i fix the onclick function with the variable?

Comment: Is that a naked closing tag for a div right there, about 4 lines from the bottom of your posted code?

Comment: onclick() doesn't need delegation.

Answer (score 0):

You can update to this to see:

```
str+="<button type='button' onclick='menu(" + m + ");'>Click Me!</button></div>";
```

---

Because in your `onclick` event the var `m` you were passing is like  a string not a varialble, if you want to pass a variable then it has to be concatenated like this.

---

#### Note:

```
</div>'; // is this required??
        str+= '</div>';
```

because as i see you are closing one div after button and another after the above `str`.

Comment: also m is defined inside an each() loop then used once at the end. Which means `m` will always have the last value assigned in the loop.

Comment: @Ramy yeah seems OP want it that way.

Comment: str+="<button type='button' onclick='menu(" + m + ");'>Click Me!</button></div>"; worked. thanks!